# Should ServletResponse isCommitted Always Be Checked Before Modifying The Response

Tags: java, http, httpresponse

The title almost speaks for itself, but is valuable to always check `isCommitted()` on type `ServletResponse`? My particular example is in using a filter where I do the following if a user isn't authorized to perform a certain action (CSRF checks to be specific):

```
if (!httpResp.isCommitted()) {
    httpResp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

In this case, it almost feels like overkill that I've checked the response. My filter is at the top of the chain, there should be nothing before it that would commit a response (let alone allow the filter chain to continue if it did), but I can't help but feel like this is an assumption which in the name of good defensive programming I shouldn't be making. I feel like it's good practice to check the status of the response.

So, all of that being said, is it valuable to check the response at this point in time? And to maybe extend this further, is it good practice to always check this *every time*  a response is modified? In my case, I can hardly find reason to support something other than an exception being thrown when a CSRF token does not match (assuming that would only happen in an attack scenario).

Comment: If you're supposed to be preventing access to the page, you don't want any other mis-written piece of software from preventing you from doing that. You want to *find* those, and not checking this will definitely help you do that, and definitely remove a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

In general, based on when some code is executed you know that the response has not been committed.  I would not add this check everywhere.

Some places I would add it:-

- a piece of library code that might be called in various different contexts
- exception handling code that might be reached before or after the response has been comitted